# Unable to do group by over tumbling window of 1 hour in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie of spark. I have a use case which I am struggling to get it done. My use case is - There is a log file generated by web-server containing logs in following format.

```
Hostname Timestamp GetOrPost ErrorCode ByteSize
141.243.1.172 [29:23:53:25] "GET /Software.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1497
query2.lycos.cs.cmu.edu [29:23:53:36] "GET /Consumer.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1325
tanuki.twics.com [29:23:53:53] "GET /News.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1014
```

**I want to group by hostname and get sum of Bytesize of each unique hostname for every hour(tumbling hour).**
My below code does group by but the output doesnt seems to be correct. Not sure what is wrong in code.

Python code:

```
import re
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, regexp_extract

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("LogAnalysis").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
base_df = sqlContext.read.text("C:/Users/Documents/log.txt")
split_df = base_df.select(regexp_extract('value', r'^([^\s]+\s)', 1).alias('host'),
                          regexp_extract('value', r'^.*\[(\d\d\/\w{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{4})]', 1).alias('timestamp'),
                          regexp_extract('value', r'^.*\s+(\d+)$', 1).cast('integer').alias('content_size'))

split_df.groupby('host').sum("content_size")
split_df.show(15,truncate=False)
```

Comment: The regexp for the timestamp does not match the example data that you have given. Maybe you could update either the example data or the regexp?

Comment: I am trying to fix the regex too. Also, looking for another way to solve it without using regex.

Comment: What is the meaning of the timestamp values that you have given in the example data?

Comment: The Timestamp is just hours in a single day from 0 to 24 hours. The format is hour:minute:seconds:milliseconds. We dont need to worry about the  date as logs are for only one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the hour from the timestamp column (just take the first two digits) and then group by host and hour.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
base_df = spark.read.text("log2.txt")
split_df = base_df.select(regexp_extract('value', r'^([^\s]+)\s', 1).alias('host'),
    regexp_extract('value', r'^.*\[(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\]', 1).alias('timestamp'),
    regexp_extract('value', r'^.*\s+(\d+)$', 1).cast('integer').alias('content_size')) \
    .filter("host <> 'Hostname'") \ 
    .withColumn('hour', F.substring(F.col('timestamp'),0,2))

split_df.groupby('host', 'hour').sum("content_size").show(15,truncate=False)
```

I have changed the regexp for the `timestamp` column.